# Jsoup select text after tag

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to extract a text after each  tag using jsoup. Is there any way to select it directly or do I have to perform .substring on the whole thing?

```
<div>
<a href="#"> I don't want this text </a> 
**I want to retrieve this text**
</div>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

    Document document = Jsoup.parse("<div>"
            + "<a href=\"#\"> I don't want this text </a>"
            + "**I want to retrieve this text**" + "</div>");

    Element a = document.select("a").first();

    Node node = a.nextSibling();
    System.out.println(node.toString());
}
```

Output

```
**I want to retrieve this text**
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer above is short of universality in spite of offering a resolving direction.

`nextSibling()` is unuseble while the html structure altered.

When I refered into Jsoup api , I found a method named `textNodes()`, which can get the list of text node from this element.

```
public static String getTextAfterTag(Element ele) {
  String text = "";
  for(TextNode node: ele.textNodes()) {
    text += node.text();
  }
  return text;
}
```

hope to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div>"
            + "<a href=\"#\"> I don't want this text </a>"
            + "**I want to retrieve this text**" + "</div>"); 

   Elements tags = doc.getElementsByTag("a");

   for(Element tag : tags) {
      System.out.println(tag.text());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

1. get the html of `<div>` first, and then select its html by using `.html()`
2. get `<a>` element, and get it's html
3. get the length of `<a>` element's html
4. exclude the first part.